# How to fill a 2d array using "%s\n" instead of " %[^\n]"

Tags: c, scanf, user-input, format-specifiers

I am fairly new to C. I want to fill a 2d array where each row is filled using a string as input.
My current solution looks as follows:

```
char word[2][100]


for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf(" %[^\n]", word[i]);
}
```

I generally understand the %[^\n] specifier but don't understand why space is needed before it in order to work.

When I try to do the same with %s things start to go weird.

```
char word[2][100]


for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf("%s", word[i]);
}
```

It allows for 3 Inputs instead of 2 and crashes my program.

Comment: `why space is needed before` The space skips over the newline left in the input stream by the previous read. `do the same with %s` You can't do the same with `%s` because that reads whitespace delimited strings, while `%[^\n]` reads everything up to a newline.

Comment: What do you mean by "it allows for 3 inputs"?  Is there a call to scanf after this loop that you're not showing?  *Always* check the value returned by scanf.  *Never* use `"%s"`.  if you want to use `"%s"`, use the maximum field limited version `"%99s"` (99 is appropriate in this case since you are reading a string into a buffer tha can hold a string with maximum length of 99)

Comment: Similarly, consider `" %99[^\n]"` to prevent the buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"%s"` skips leading white-space, even without a leading `" "`, like `' '` and the previous line's `'\n'`  due to <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`" %[^\n]"` also skips leading white-space due to the `" "`, else it does not.  Then it looks for non-`'\n'` input.

Both are *bad* as they lack width control and neither properly reads a *line*.

---

Consider avoiding `scanf()` and use `fgets()`.

```
char word[2][100] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  char buffer[100 + 1];
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) break;
  buffer[strcpsn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential trailing \n
  
  strcpy(word[i], buffer);
}
```

There are additional concerns too, but something to get OP started.